# ImageMagick в Windows 7

Tags: windows, apache, php, imagemagick

Всем здравствуйте!
Довольно долгое время не могу решить проблему установки ImageMagick под Windows, с самой программой проблем нет, а вот с php расширением запара, пробовал много разных dll, перечитал много мануалов по этой теме, но всё в пустую. Чаще всего Apache выдает ошибку, однако, когда нахожу dll при котором сервер запускается, при этом через команду phpinfo(), ImageMagick не видно.

Очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

P.S. Уже задумываюсь о переходе на Ubuntu, там вроде эта установка практически ничего не занимает, но это очень не желаемый вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше переходите на Ubuntu. Я тоже об этом подумываю, столько раз пытался на Винду поставить этот ImageMagick и всё напрасно, зато под линуксовые оси говорят в пару кликов всё делается. Ну или как альтернативу поставьте виртуалку и на неё Ubuntu специально для программирования.

Comment: Да, однозначно, дальше виртуального Ubuntu я не уйду)))

Comment: А что с Ubuntu не так?

Comment: Ubuntu не Windows, и просто так взять и полностью перейти на него, не каждый сможет

Comment: Какой Вы странный. Говорите про виртуалку, а потом "полностью перейти". Винды-то у Вас никуда не пропадут (по крайней мере пока).